# How to stop command window from closing after hitting enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am a complete beginner so I really have no idea what I'm doing.

```
namespace first_program
{
  class first_program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
      Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }
}
```

I am using VS Code and whenever I run this code the command prompt opens up, but whenever I press enter after typing into it the window closes.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it a bug with VS Studio?

I have copied all of this code from a Youtube tutorial by Brackeys titled "How to Program in C#"

It also my be important for me to note that a message saying "The program '[10260] first program.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." pops up in the debug terminal.

Comment: It's standard behavior for the IDEs to close the command window after the app is executed. You can add ReadLine at the end of your code, so it will wait for "Enter" after everything is done. Or you can launch app from the terminal window, integrated into VS Code, for example

Comment: add another Console.ReadLine() at the end

Comment: Exit code 0 means - application finished without errors.

Comment: May I know if the answer can solve your problem? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out. If it works you can consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Place Console.ReadKey() after the writeLine stuff, and it will wait for a keyboard interaction to close.